# JavaScript (google script) function sometimes works, sometimes not : what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, random, google-sheets

I have an array containing values (values from a google sheet), and two functions that generate random values to pick values from the array :

the random function #1 :

```
function hasardSingPlur(){
  var values = [0,1];
  return (values[Math.floor(Math.random()*2)]);
}
```

random generator function #2 :

```
function hasardNombreMax(){
   return (Math.floor((Math.random() * nombreMax) + 1))
}
```

the function to get the random elements :

```
function generate() {
  var nom = noms[hasardNombreMax(nombreMax)][hasardSingPlur()];
  Logger.log(nom);
}
```

If I test the generate() function a hundred times, it sometimes goes to the end and outputs 100 values, but it sometimes stops after random number of values...

```
function test(){
  for(var i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++){
    Logger.log(generate());
      }
}
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: Impossible to read property "1.0" from undefined.
```

Strange behavior, and I really don't understand why.

EDIT : here is the entire code  :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var reservoir = ss.getSheetByName("réservoir");
var generateur = ss.getSheetByName("générateur");
var nombreMax = reservoir.getLastRow()-1;

// 0 noms au singulier, 1 noms au pluriel, 2 genre 
// 3 adjectifs (masc. sing.), 4 adjectifs(masc. pluriel), 5 adjectifs (fém. sing), 6 adjectifs (fém. plur.), 
// 7 phrases subordonnées sujet singulier 8 phrases subordonnées sujet au pluriel, 
// 9 groupes prépositionnels, 
// 10 verbes principaux (3e pers. sing), 11 verbes principaux (3e pers. pluriel)
var noms = reservoir.getRange(2, 1, nombreMax, 3).getValues();
var ajectifs = reservoir.getRange(2, 4, nombreMax, 4).getValues();
var pSubs = reservoir.getRange(2, 8, nombreMax, 2);
var grPreps = reservoir.getRange(2, 10, nombreMax, 1).getValues();

function generate() {
  var nom = noms[hasardNombreMax(nombreMax)][hasardSingPlur()];
  Logger.log(nom);
}


// renvoie 1 ou 2 pour choisir si singulier ou pluriel, masculin ou féminin
function hasardSingPlur(){
  var values = [0,1];
  return (values[Math.floor(Math.random()*2)]);
}

// renvoie un nombre au hasard pour choisir un élément au hasard dans le tableau
function hasardNombreMax(){
   return (Math.floor((Math.random() * nombreMax) + 1))
}

function test(){
  for(var i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++){
    Logger.log(generate());
      }
}
```

Comment: Is `nombreMax` a global var?

Comment: @Hackerman : yes, it is. I've suspected it to be the culprit and I've read some stuff about global vars, and even tested some things to be sure I wasn't doing anything wrong. If the generate() function outputs some values, it must not be because of some global scope reason. Or not ?

Comment: Side question: for `hasardSingPlur` why bother having an array? your index is the same as your value at that index, so why not just return the index you're generating instead?

Comment: Also, where is `noms` defined?

Comment: I've added the entire code, in order to be fully understandable.

Comment: Good one @Andrew_CS . That function should be just something like `function hasardSingPlur(){
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
}`

Comment: @Andrew_CS : well, I am not exactly a great coder ;-) . I was not sure 'Math.floor((Math.random() * 1) )' would sometimes output a zero value. Should have tried, though.

Comment: @Andrew_CS you gave the answer : why bother with an array... Fixed it and it works. Thanks for pointing it

Comment: @RomainSchmid I wasn't sure either, but I looked up the documentation on the functions to make sure :), glad it helped!